# differences between fake computer-generated data & real data

Tags: dataset, computational-statistics, random-generation

generally, is there a/some formula(s) or algorithm(s) to prove that a data set is a fake one generated using computer and not by field work?
more specific, recently I got a research questionnaire data (with likert scale) which I believe is not real. firstly everything is way too nice considering old results within the same subject; descriptives, correlations, reliability, PCA & factor analysis etc. secondly data collection processes ended quite sooner than usual and ... there are more reasons and I can not prove anything.
I think the answer is "no you can't" but I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You may be able to show some good reasons for suspicion, but proving it beyond reasonable levels of doubt from the *data alone* may be difficult. [Often simple investigative techniques reveal the actual situation (like investigating where and when was the testing conducted, but it turns out they didn't book the rooms they claim to have done it in and some other group was using the at the time, or someone that they said entered the data wasn't even employed by them at the time; it's simple factual details that tend to unravel the stories even though the data may be quite suspicious.]